# Unable to login to Data loader for production instance, but able to login into sandbox

Tags: data, login, loader

I am NOT able to login into production instance (https://login.salesforce.com) using password+security token.

However, I am able to login into dataloader for sandbox instance (https://test/salesforce.com) using password+security token.

If I use another laptop, I am able to login to data loader for production instance which is good, but as that laptop has Windows 10 so data loader doesn't work properly.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the latest data loader? Maybe you are using an old one...

Comment: Hello, I notice some contradictions in your question. First you say it does not work in production and it works in sandbox. Later you say that you can login in dataloader for production. And what do you mean by it does not work properly on windows 10?

Comment: @Satish you can always update the question with more data points. No need to raise new question for same issue.